# Python: Encode Base64 to Basic connect to an API

Tags: python, json, api, authentication

I'm trying to connect to an API and I've to encode64 the username and password. The 'Authorisation' value should look like this: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ

When I try to connect I get an error: 'Unauthorized: Bad credentials'. The support says that my credentials are ok, but they are slow to respond to solve my issue.

I suspect the encoding part of the code, but I'm not sure. Could you please take a look at my code and tell me what could be wrong with it?

The direct link to the section about authentication in the documentation :
http://developer.outbrain.com/home-page/amplify-api/documentation/#/reference/authentications/via-api

```
m = str(base64.b64encode(b'xxxxx:xxxxxxx'))
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + m + ''
}
r = requests.get('https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/login', headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Re: documentation link, "Not Found. The requested URL /home-page/amplify-api/documentation/ was not found on this server."

Comment: IT works on my end on an incognito window. Maybe copy-past the link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `decode` to correctly get a string from the byte sequence:

Wrong (note the 'b' prefix and single quotes in the result):

```
>>> str(base64.b64encode(b'test'))
"b'dGVzdA=='"
```

Right:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(b'test').decode('utf-8')
'dGVzdA=='
```

Additionally, `requests` can do this for you:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
r = requests.get('https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/login', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to solve my authentication issue.

Comment: @CreekBarbara Ok, to rule out any other possible mistakes, you can see my edit for how to let requests handle the authorization for you. If that doesn't work, I would have to think it's the credentials or an issue on their end.

Comment: Still bad credentials! The credentials work with PHP though and it connects ok. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, now that is bizarre. Can you access the base64-encoded string you're computing with PHP and compare it to what you're computing in Python?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can't. I don't have access to the code, but I can see when it connected the last time to the platform and it was 8 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
import base64
    
message = "user:password"
message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(message_bytes)
base64_message = base64_bytes.decode('ascii')
        
print(base64_message)
```