# Translating curl to Python requests (post)

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request in the following format

```
body=$(cat << EOF
{
  "order": {
    "units": "100",
    "instrument": "EUR_USD",
    "timeInForce": "FOK",
    "type": "MARKET",
    "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
EOF
)

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

I hope to have your help translating this into requests.post format.

This is what I have currently, and it doesnt seem to work:

```
order_data = {
"order": {
"units": "100",
"instrument": "EUR_USD",
"timeInForce": "FOK",
"type": "MARKET",
"positionFill": "DEFAULT"
},
'Authorization': 'Bearer '+<AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>
}

requests.post('https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders', data = order_data)
```

I have replaced ACCOUNT and AUTHENTICATION TOKEN with actual strings.

The part I am confused with is the body=$() line. Not too sure how to fit that into the requests format.

Hope to have your help. Thank you.

Comment: It seems the API expects JSON data, try the `json` parameter.

Comment: Also set h = {"Authorization: Bearer": "<AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" }... it may also need some encoding on the token...  I can't tell without trying to make a request to your api myself...  so it will be similar to  r = requests.post(url, headers=h, json=data)

Comment: By encoding I mean similar to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139093/base64-authentication-python  So possibly {"Authorization": "Bearer" + base64.b64encode("<AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>") }

Comment: can you show response headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Authorization` should be passed as header, `Content-Type` must be `'application/json'` and payload must be json encoded.

As of Requests version 2.4.2 and onwards, you can alternatively use 'json' parameter in the call which makes it simpler.

The final payload should be as follows:

```
order_data = {
"order": {
"units": "100",
"instrument": "EUR_USD",
"timeInForce": "FOK",
"type": "MARKET",
"positionFill": "DEFAULT"
}
}
headers = 'Authorization': 'Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>'

requests.post('https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders', headers=headers, json=order_data)
```

> Using the json parameter in the request will change the `Content-Type` in the header to `application/json`.

Docs here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: thanks @Debendra! separating headers and json data did the trick.